# How do I verify if I have downloaded Xcode correctly?

Tags: xcode, md5, checksum

There is a way in software to test whether it has downloaded correctly, I believe it is called a MD5 digest, or has something to do with MD5 or checksums; I can't remember exactly what it is called.

Is there such a tool or service with regards to Xcode?  And if so, is there a link I can go to find out more?

I am wondering if the Xcode I downloade has downloaded correctly, fully or not; and this might be the reason why my Xcode is not archiving anything with regards to Ad hoc provisioning profiles?

If there is such a tool, please post a link.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode is downloaded as a Disk Image. Disk Images already have built-in checksumming, so if the disk image mounts on your desktop you know it's correct.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess it must not be that then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to md5sum each file inside `Install Xcode.app` and then output the md5 to a file, then check each md5 using `md5sum -c`:

```
[ 15:11 Jonathan@MacBookPro /Applications ]$ find /Applications/Install\ Xcode.app/ -type f -exec md5sum {} >> ~/xcode.md5 \;
[ 15:13 Jonathan@MacBookPro /Applications ]$ md5sum -c ~/xcode.md5 
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Info.plist: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Library/LaunchServices/com.apple.dt.InstallXcodeHelper: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/MacOS/Install Xcode: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/PkgInfo: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/.changedIcons: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/App.icns: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/ASIInstallStepsView.nib: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/ASIServiceLevelAgreementView.nib: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/ASIWindow.nib: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/BackgroundNoise.png: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/en.lproj/License.rtf: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/InstallerSuccess.png: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/InstallerWindowBackground.png: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/InstallerWindowBackgroundReflection.png: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/ApplicationLoader.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/BluetoothSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/clang.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/CoreAudioSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/Dashcode.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevDocumentation.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperDiskImage4_3.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperDiskImageReleased.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperTools.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperToolsSystemSupport.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevSamples.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevToolsDocumentation.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DistributedBuildsSupport.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DocDownloadOff.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DocDownloadOn.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/FireWireSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/gcc4.2.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneDocumentation.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneHostSideTools.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_0.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_1.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_1_2.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_1_3.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_0.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_1.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_2.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_3.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDKSnowLeopardExtras.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDKTools.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDK4_3.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDK4_3Patch1.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDKTools.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSystemComponents.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/JavaSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/llvm-gcc4.2.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/MacOSX10.6.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/MacOSX10.7.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDevice.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/NetworkLinkConditioner.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/OpenGLApps.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/OpenGLSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/OtherDevDocumentation.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/QuickTimeSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/RelocatableScript.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/SourceControl.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/SystemScript.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/VersionedDeveloperToolsSystemSupport.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/WebKitSDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/X11Documentation.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/X11SDK.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeEssentialsSystemSupport.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeiPhonePlugins.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeTools.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeUserSystemSupport.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/xcrun.pkg: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Warning.png: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.icns: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Info.plist: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/iPhoneSDKSL.dist: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/background.tiff: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Description.plist: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Localizable.strings: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/VolumeCheck.strings: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Welcome.rtf: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/tempfileexists: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/version.plist: OK
/Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/version.plist: OK

[ 15:13 Jonathan@MacBookPro /Applications ]$ cat ~/xcode.md5 
02776ca82dd8aa682191e1963f724036  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
74903dc4cac1e8bad9164da8be8e7061  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt
2c02cab4169b46268e3a4c9da6e44ed9  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Info.plist
73641e067067a015e1294e1f269baf7c  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Library/LaunchServices/com.apple.dt.InstallXcodeHelper
8c6ddd0c2428cf15e8ad7acc7ac675ab  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/MacOS/Install Xcode
23b7d7d024abb0f558420e098800bf27  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/PkgInfo
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/.changedIcons
d765f49bf8e41b5cb9a57397aa1d3b86  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/App.icns
9e66a1ab5d934573bf7e5e6a985a7291  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/ASIInstallStepsView.nib
3fa8f564ca2eb803dd41989e2dc865cb  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/ASIServiceLevelAgreementView.nib
7708c0438c5d3a75ac358a2d5e6adc4a  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/ASIWindow.nib
37e0c9ecad540a290bf885ffe71ca409  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/BackgroundNoise.png
ce7f5b3d4bfc7b4b0da6a06dccc515f2  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
345af599793f8dbe869e0f5372b6e748  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/en.lproj/License.rtf
c4e71a30ee5a7e270671a9f9896a17ce  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib
9d8b2c24a2792349cf5a6f2f12c4ddf7  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/InstallerSuccess.png
39b1b0bc7a50a57e0dfd96398d9ad033  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/InstallerWindowBackground.png
6e5d4e9a742e7b162c9fdba6661eb1c1  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/InstallerWindowBackgroundReflection.png
c4d5d08bc6778e38b47ec4d8b020b92f  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/ApplicationLoader.pkg
532d3f9a4d24964e2095784d6e4c49e2  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/BluetoothSDK.pkg
d1fb42943ac45e4c36d41130e35cfdaf  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/clang.pkg
b01ccfba1fda15e8aef9110e251e3758  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/CoreAudioSDK.pkg
6637837f66970f2a434129fff1e476e1  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/Dashcode.pkg
c551505c6d81f1814782681c0aeb19b7  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevDocumentation.pkg
a6fdb1208fdcf24f2dbcc76e1f662980  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperDiskImage4_3.pkg
33489ab47bf38f4546c0db15c4cc0eaf  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperDiskImageReleased.pkg
be08842d0bdc32cca1d46415e763182d  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperTools.pkg
0912dd8dbed7aab7b1a0f94c9bd93686  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg
b221f8f5f387baba204be2320c0bd054  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperToolsSystemSupport.pkg
ea4c5e09c312d1f0120531f9ae70430c  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevSamples.pkg
0089da4b32e10c2c070ee4b388522873  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevSDK.pkg
178ca07556be309b7359da4724bd3891  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DevToolsDocumentation.pkg
9ee086e320d9f3ea7cf9414f20344c73  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DistributedBuildsSupport.pkg
9a6b0bd945ca103f9e7e3c950fd2ad7d  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DocDownloadOff.pkg
c9d9ec136be1c841bb8f9da60007dc61  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/DocDownloadOn.pkg
8fb7d46f3b28b1c7524b12928eaf3cd5  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/FireWireSDK.pkg
626b08391682b1468dfb82e06bd61d6f  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/gcc4.2.pkg
afb754a601c561f1b0f0d76e520936dd  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneDocumentation.pkg
a2f46f26f7a8b90eaae660e08527a184  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneHostSideTools.pkg
0a52f6b5530a74ece17c56ce9ea5cbae  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_0.pkg
44c4434b93f45ca2f4a8a4fdf4dc32c7  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_1.pkg
fd2b0a9888b97840b034e5acf8853e85  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_1_2.pkg
a8566312f7c17c869356c54b723c7df6  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_1_3.pkg
3da3fffefe33eb4fe51e9af6a04e5f28  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_2.pkg
434dab3a714700cfd353295bca03108f  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_0.pkg
59960cf68fcb3de47bd3ff21736e91eb  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_1.pkg
731adda7c943973c14345683405158c2  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_2.pkg
9e670c5aef604c2e6c88a9fc489bd9d0  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDK4_3.pkg
9ab8de52cfb996b821e679384f55021c  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDKSnowLeopardExtras.pkg
4ceff0fd74fbd289766ca5ca7b054039  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSDKTools.pkg
ec9a846281b562c921893d96fd6fde59  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDK4_3.pkg
3d2357bc0f5bc872dd17c668881cf6cb  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDK4_3Patch1.pkg
1617c8ed85c129996bafccb733b1966d  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDKTools.pkg
92b6340c2a9897ea207eaef8eb95905f  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/iPhoneSystemComponents.pkg
b1adee172e464d6f240dd80ee19cc9ea  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/JavaSDK.pkg
4382343ea2a8dbf50afdfcff769a8d28  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/llvm-gcc4.2.pkg
684d2af26c55a314e528218b624c39f5  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/MacOSX10.6.pkg
f91e21bf85b7e61574d71226c3238d41  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/MacOSX10.7.pkg
63c71dd9c142bc7f2cbb40065fbfa0ec  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDevice.pkg
55359667239d4779127a90c7b361ea9e  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/NetworkLinkConditioner.pkg
3908ceb5d75967ebdf2c6a546b278eba  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/OpenGLApps.pkg
a28f4fc32a180c676157eeaf875938a6  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/OpenGLSDK.pkg
08edfcd887bb203c967be621c8da967b  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/OtherDevDocumentation.pkg
f48375f833aa2fb62af03e91145e36f4  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/QuickTimeSDK.pkg
7c51f8cf9585406615a487838ab00a47  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/RelocatableScript.pkg
c0744d024789f1775f9a56d36ef9ce35  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/SourceControl.pkg
587c9d1662e7d8a16c4c0804686b3f1c  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/SystemScript.pkg
6499aa181373491c98f75d8b20480cec  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/VersionedDeveloperToolsSystemSupport.pkg
b03d657f2a47d38db97a9f454be0b3f8  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/WebKitSDK.pkg
4035efdda2bc01a34e3f2db153ee6737  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/X11Documentation.pkg
a1a48600fac5c180668fd4bdba396a2d  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/X11SDK.pkg
f89291f210eb7013f58976cd87aeb1d8  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeEssentialsSystemSupport.pkg
25ed260b658774a2f58d1348c4e69dd8  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeiPhonePlugins.pkg
a6098a171b9f9f3f62e8dd2e469c91f3  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeTools.pkg
e56ce95c256aef9b3328e9b065492ee3  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeUserSystemSupport.pkg
d80c6157f7c50b9ffbb3ae174bacdfba  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Packages/xcrun.pkg
02711bb14cbb0f4ec62b63df4545a990  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Warning.png
3ac48bd8150d97fa1931f2c0b114f297  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.icns
8053eb77c72f22324f69df111d19a823  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Info.plist
2550341e6e54cc89db8dfdd2887dac8c  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/iPhoneSDKSL.dist
881e5d4ff2bd7bdd3f4e046b09a7668d  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/background.tiff
e6cd9d8631747572335cc10d6b3fab88  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Description.plist
345af599793f8dbe869e0f5372b6e748  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf
e550fc264cbe19521842b5b7d030ce05  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Localizable.strings
996633e2cfd4b0fafe4f8638286e40db  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/VolumeCheck.strings
e732ae46abee1181dbc1221d1f9d7a57  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Welcome.rtf
b1240db1b9ef943076bac4a404f1fcac  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/Resources/tempfileexists
45a160aeaffc4d54c530ba322e6b2f03  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/Contents/version.plist
75bb4e64677740ebaeccf6ab09503048  /Applications/Install Xcode.app//Contents/version.plist
```

Comment: Gave your idea a try, but I get a message saying "find: md5sum: No such file or directory". I tried md5sum and it says "md5sum: command not found".  I tried "port install md5sum" but it says so "Port md5sum not found" :(

Comment: `md5sum` existed on older versions of OS X, but it doesn't exist on 10.7 and I'm not sure it even existed on 10.6.

Comment: @Kevin My macbook pro is 2 weeks old, came with 10.7, and it had md5sum installed already.  Weird.

Comment: @chown: Did you migrate from another computer? Perhaps you had md5sum installed as a third-party tool?

Comment: @KevinBallard Oh yea, I guess I did copy over some stuff from my old MacBookAir, I dont remember copying over md5sum but since its in `/usr/local/bin/md5sum` I must have.  Good call!

Comment: For the record, the equivalent tool now is `openssl md5 <files>`, though it uses a slightly different output format.

Comment: I'll give it a go in a few hours, either that or just download XCode again (which i already have an another machine)

Comment: It turns out that I must have got a corrupted Xcode or it was conflicting with an older version; I have since resolved the problem b y assuming I had a a corrupted copy and redownloaded XCode again via a faster line -- thankfully I got an archive!